Can I use a single target spell on a creature I can't see?
I was looking at the spell Mind Thrust I; in this situation, I was aware of a target, and I knew what square she was in, but because of Obscuring Mist, I couldn't actually see her. The actual text of the spell is:

Range: close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels);
Target: one creature;
Duration: instantaneous;
Saving Throw: Will half; Spell Resistance: yes


You divine the most vulnerable portions of your opponent’s mind and overload it with a glut of psychic information. This attack deals 1d6 points of damage per caster level (maximum 5d6). The target receives a Will save for half damage. This attack has no effect on creatures without an Intelligence score.

There's nothing about needing to see the target, but I'm not sure how else they would be targeted. I was looking in the magic rules, but I couldn't find anything saying that I would need to see them (but I may just be missing something).
RAW, in this situation, could I use Mind Thrust on this target? And, if yes, if I didn't know her exact square, but I knew there was an enemy in a general area, could I use it?

There is a general rule you need to see or touch the target
This is from the Magic chapter, under Target or Targets:

Some spells have a target or targets. You cast these spells on creatures or objects, as defined by the spell itself. You must be able to see or touch the target, and you must specifically choose that target.

So you cannot cast the spell if you cannot see or are not touching the target.
Spells that do allow you to target a creature you cannot see or are not touching exist, but they specifically tell you they can do this, like Scrying, which wouldn't make sense if you already could see the creature to begin with.

You should add that there are spells that explicitly allow targeting things you can’t see.

@DaleM I can't think of any — do you have an example?

Dream is an example - there are others

@DaleM Maybe another would be better, as Dream's target is given as "one living creature touched" (the messenger, rather than the recipient, although I agree the recipient can be considered target too. But this helped me think of Scrying, which might be a more direct example.
